# Complete express req not in apollo-server-express

Tags: express, apollo, apollo-server

Below you can see I have an Apollo server (using express). In lines 33-39 I use an express middleware to check an auth token and (if the token is valid) set the users _id onto the request object.

In my server constructor, I set the context to return the req, as well as the _id as the userId.  I have also tried just doing `({req}) => {..req}`.

No matter what I am trying, I am not getting acces to the userId in the apollo context. I've made a simple gql query resolver in Apollo to just log out the value, and it's always undefined.

Furthermore, I have a simple REST route (lines 43-49) that seem to attach the userId to every request just fine, so something isn't connecting, but I'm not sure where.

At the end of the day my goal is to receive a JWT token from a cookie sent client side, verify it, and add it the context so I can access the values in my graphQL resolvers. Any thoughts?

#### index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
require('dotenv').config();

const db = require('./db');
const User = require('./models/User');

const typeDefs = require('./gqlSchema');
const queries = require('./resolvers/queries');
const mutations = require('./resolvers/mutations');

const resolvers = {
  Mutation: mutations,
  Query: queries,
}

const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
  origin: process.env.FRONTEND_URL,
  credentials: true,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const { token } = req.cookies;
  if (token) {
    const tokenData = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
    req._id = tokenData._id;
  }
  next();
})

//// TEMP REST LOGIN ////
const login = require('./controllers/login');
app.post('/auth/google', login);

app.post('/token', (req, res) => {
  console.log('/token middlware req: ', req._id);
  res.send('test token route')
})
///////////////////

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: ({ req }) => ({
    ...req,
    userId: req._id,
  })
});

server.applyMiddleware({
  app,
  path: '/graphql',
  cors: false,
});

app.listen({ port: 4000 }, () => {
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`);
})
```

Comment: Have you logged out the req object in the context function? If yes, is everything there?